# How to get rid of a scratch on my strat

Tags: guitar, instruments, maintenance

I know that it's possible to rub out a  scratch on my cars finish using rubbing and polishing compound. Does the same thing work on a guitars finish if the scratch is not to deep?

Comment: Assuming the finish is cellulose, and it may well be - ask Fender, with model and s.n. then the process is the same as with car paintwork (when they used celly paint !  Or - leave it, and when it gathers many more, and you're famous, Fender will make copies to sell at ridiculous prices...

Comment: Your comment implies when my guitar gets scratched up, I'll be famous.  :)

Comment: The two things have been known to happen in that order!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to answer your question, yes you can use car scratch remover, but go gently. In addition, try it on a hidden area first.